# UIButton pressed, other one doesn't press

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton

hi I have some code that creates two buttons and when a button is pressed an trigger is set and it changes the background and the text colour.

How could i make it so that once one is pressed the other cannot be pressed.

This creates the buttons

```
//learnmore button
UIButton *learnmorebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self.view addSubview:learnmorebutton];
learnmorebutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
learnmorebutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 518.0, 159.0, 50.0);
[learnmorebutton setTitle:@"learn more" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[learnmorebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
learnmorebutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:17.0];


//signup button
UIButton *signup = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.view addSubview:signup];
signup.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
signup.frame = CGRectMake(162.0, 518.0, 160.0, 50.0);
[signup setTitle:@"sign up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
signup.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:17.0];
signup.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

These are the two triggers

```
   [learnmorebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(learnMoreClickEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [signup addTarget:self action:@selector(signupClickEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

These are the two events

```
- (void)learnMoreClickEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //sender is the button that was tapped
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


}

- (void)signupClickEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //sender is the button that was tapped
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];


}
```

thanks all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like rckoenes mentioned you can declare those UIButton as properties and do that.. or

**Assign Tags like this**

```
//learnmore button
UIButton *learnmorebutton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
learnmorebutton.tag = 10;
learnmorebutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
learnmorebutton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 518.0, 159.0, 50.0);
[learnmorebutton setTitle:@"learn more" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[learnmorebutton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
learnmorebutton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:17.0];
[learnmorebutton addTarget:self action:@selector(learnMoreClickEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:learnmorebutton];

//signup button
UIButton *signup = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
signup.tag = 20;
signup.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.3];
signup.frame = CGRectMake(162.0, 518.0, 160.0, 50.0);
[signup setTitle:@"sign up" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
signup.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:17.0];
signup.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:signup];
[signup addTarget:self action:@selector(signupClickEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

**By Using tags to access the buttons**

```
- (void)learnMoreClickEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *signUp = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:20]
    signUp.enabled = NO;
    //sender is the button that was tapped
    [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)signupClickEvent:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIButton *learnmorebutton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:10]
    learnmorebutton.enabled = NO;
   //sender is the button that was tapped
   [sender setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Hope this gives you an Idea.
Basically if your looking for toggling, you can always use UISegementControl. I mean it depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You start by keep a reference to the button, preferably properties on the viewController that creates these buttons.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *learnmorebutton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *signup;

@end;
```

Then in the method either disable the button:

```
<button>.enabled = NO:
```

Or hide it:

```
<button>.hidden = YES:
```

Comment: I have done that but within the VOID (sender). I can select the button self.learnmorebutton but it doesn't work. but learnmorebutton.enabled = NO works in view did load

Answer (score -1):

Set the enabled property of the button you want to disable to NO: `<button>.enabled = NO;`